# Python Pandas - Pivot a csv file into a specific format

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, pandas

It's my first attempt at using pandas. I really need help with pivot_table. None of the combinations I used seem to work.

I have a csv file like this:

```
Id  Param1          Param2
1   -5.00138282776  2.04990620034E-08
1   -4.80147838593  2.01516989762E-08
1   -4.60159301758  1.98263165885E-08
1   -4.40133094788  1.94918392538E-08
1   -4.20143127441  1.91767686175E-08
1   -4.00122880936  1.88457374151E-08

2   -5.00141859055  6.88369405921E-09
2   -4.80152130127  6.77335965094E-09
2   -4.60163593292  6.65415056389E-09
2   -4.40139055252  6.54434062497E-09

3   -5.00138044357  1.16316911658E-08
3   -4.80148792267  1.15515588206E-08
3   -4.60160970688  1.14048361866E-08
3   -4.40137386322  1.12357021465E-08
3   -4.20145988464  1.11049178741E-08
```

I want my final output to be like this:

```
Param1_for_Id1  Param2_for_Id1     Param1_for_Id2   Param2_for_Id2      Param1_for_Id3  Param2_for_Id3
-5.00138282776  2.04990620034E-08  -5.00141859055   6.88369405921E-09  -5.00138044357  1.16316911658E-08
-4.80147838593  2.01516989762E-08  -4.80152130127   6.77335965094E-09  -4.80148792267  1.15515588206E-08
-4.60159301758  1.98263165885E-08  -4.60163593292   6.65415056389E-09  -4.60160970688  1.14048361866E-08
-4.40133094788  1.94918392538E-08  -4.40139055252   6.54434062497E-09  -4.40137386322  1.12357021465E-08
-4.20143127441  1.91767686175E-08                                      -4.20145988464  1.11049178741E-08  
-4.00122880936  1.88457374151E-08
```

I can't figure out how to reshape my data. Any help would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_index` X2 + `unstack`:

```
v = (df.set_index('Id')  # optional, omit if `Id` is the index
       .set_index(df.groupby('Id').cumcount(), append=True)
       .unstack(0)
       .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
       .fillna('')       # I actually don't recommend adding this step in
)
v.columns = v.columns.map('{0[0]}_for_Id{0[1]}'.format)
```

And now,

```
print(v)

   Param1_for_Id1  Param2_for_Id1 Param1_for_Id2 Param2_for_Id2  \
0       -5.001383    2.049906e-08       -5.00142    6.88369e-09   
1       -4.801478    2.015170e-08       -4.80152    6.77336e-09   
2       -4.601593    1.982632e-08       -4.60164    6.65415e-09   
3       -4.401331    1.949184e-08       -4.40139    6.54434e-09   
4       -4.201431    1.917677e-08                                 
5       -4.001229    1.884574e-08                                 

  Param1_for_Id3 Param2_for_Id3  
0       -5.00138    1.16317e-08  
1       -4.80149    1.15516e-08  
2       -4.60161    1.14048e-08  
3       -4.40137    1.12357e-08  
4       -4.20146    1.11049e-08  
5
```

Note that that last `fillna` step results in mixed strings and numeric data, so I don't recommend adding that step if you're going to do more with this output.